# pr2_controller_interface inheritance

Tags: ros, pr2-controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

Using a differential wheeled robot, I'm trying to clean up my controller programs : I used a controller for each wheel in two different package, whereas they are very very similar ! But now, the left wheel controller inherits from the WheelController class, which inherits from the pr2_controller_interface::Controller class (as in the tutorials).

I built the library for the left wheel controller, and specified the base class was the WheelController class (with PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS and in the controller_plugins.xml file). I got the following when i try to load the controller after running my robot in gazebo :

> Could not load class wheelcontroller/LeftWheelControllerPlugin: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class wheelcontroller/LeftWheelControllerPlugin with base class type pr2_controller_interface::Controller does not exist.

Is the problem that my controller does not directly inherit from the pr2_controller_interface::Controller class? I tried specifying that class instead of the WheelController class, but it still fails.

Any idea?

UP ! (again)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45602/pr2_controller_interface-inheritance/) by [arzhed](https://answers.ros.org/users/3249/arzhed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you declare your controller plugin in a pluginlib xml file and register it in your manifest's export section? Have a look [here](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller), section 5 for more information.

Btw. at least on the PR2, there exists only one controller plugin that controls all 4 casters instead of having one controller for each motor or caster.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arzhed](https://answers.ros.org/users/3249/arzhed/) on 2012-10-15**:
I did, but I didnt know what to declare as "base_class" : it should be my WheelController class that inherits from pr2_controller_interface, but it caused errors, so I declared pr2_controller_interface as base class, neither did it work. I'm gonna go with only 1 controler plugin as you said, thanks!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-15**:
The error above indicates that the class LeftWheelControllerPlugin hasn't been declared properly either with the macro PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS or the xml file. As base class, you should always specify the interface you are implementing since that is the information pluginlib needs.